# How to hide terminated pods from Grafana dashboards

Tags: kubernetes, grafana

I'm using Grafana dashboards packaged with [DigitalOcean Kubernetes Monitoring Stack](https://marketplace.digitalocean.com/apps/kubernetes-monitoring-stack). I would like my pod select dropdowns in dashboards to hide terminated pods, as I have a lot of them in there and only care about the running ones. I presume I should edit the queries somewhere but am not familiar with them so appreciate any pointers, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To change this in Grafana, open the  `Variables`  menu, then change  `$pod`  variable to refresh  `On Time Range Change`:
>
> [image]

Source: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/6308/keeping-graphs-of-terminated-kubernetes-pods-in-prometheus-grafana

Hope it helps.